# How to hide tooltip when printing a document

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, printing

I'm using Bootstrap tooltip when you hover over any buttons, so I've got a button called "Print", when you press on it Chrome shows you preview of my page I would like to print with tooltip above the "Print" button. How can I hide it using jQuery because it doesn't need to be printed?

```
<a id="print" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Print" onclick="Print()">
  <i class="fa fa-print fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
```

```js
function Print(){
  window.print();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out myself:

```
@media print {
  .tooltip { visibility: hidden; }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

To achieve this you can use the `@media` setting to hide the Bootstrap tooltips when the page is printed, like this:

```
@media print {
  .tooltip { display: none; }
}
```

Comment: @DmitryStolbov you should only ever use `!important` as a last resort - usually when you need to amend content injected by a third party. A much better idea is to structure your rules properly so that the order of precedence applies the correct styling for the given situation.

Comment: Thank you! It code has work in my case with `!important` declaration:
`@media print {
  .tooltip { display: none !important; }
}`

Comment: bootstrap uses `display:block` in the popover element style attribute so you have to override this with `!important` or @Deniss visibility instead

Comment: @Richard you don't have to use `!important`, a better approach would be to make the selector more specific, eg. `#container > div.foo .tooltip { display: none; }`